# SvelteKit unable to set cookie

Tags: cookies, svelte, sveltekit

Using SvelteKit 1.0.0-next.571
My application has a login route with:

1. +page.server.ts => redirects to / if locals.user is set
2. +page.svelte => show login page
3. signin/+server.ts => Login and get a jwt from graphql app running on the same machine.

+server.ts:

```
[..]
let gqlResponse = await response.json(); 
     
    if ( gqlResponse.errors ) { 
        console.log("ERRORS FROM GRAPHQL MIDDLEWARE:", gqlResponse.errors);
        return json( { error: gqlResponse.errors, isException: true } );
    }
    
    if (gqlResponse.data.login.user && !gqlResponse.data.login.error) {
        
        opts.cookies.set('jwt', gqlResponse.data.login.token, {
            path: '/',
            maxAge: SESSION_MAX_AGE
        });
        
        opts.setHeaders( { 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true' } )
        opts.setHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    } 
    
    return json( gqlResponse.data.login );
```

and the login handler in +page.svelte :

```
[..]
        const fetchOptions = { 
            method: 'POST',
            //mode: 'no-cors',
            //redirect: 'follow' as RequestRedirect,
            body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
            credentials: 'include' as RequestCredentials
        }

        try {

            const response = await fetch('/login/signin', fetchOptions);
            const login = await response.json(); 
    
            if (login.error) {
                handleError(login);
                return false;
            }
        
        } catch (e) {
            return handleException(e);
        }

         goto('/', { replaceState: true, invalidateAll: true} );
```

This works fine in localhost, but connecting another device to the local network **does not set any cookies** making impossible to login:

Local:   http://localhost:5173/
➜  Network: http://192.168.x.x:5173/

I also tried with different fetch options and cookie settings like:

```
opts.cookies.set('jwt', gqlResponse.data.login.token, {
    path: '/',
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'strict',
    //  secure: true
    maxAge: SESSION_MAX_AGE
});
```

but no luck, and now 'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The secure parameter only allows cookies to be set if you are only using the https protocol

Try setting secure to false in the cookies options

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34810752)